# Chen's theorem in which constituent primes are close together

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Chen's theorem states that every sufficiently large even integer can be written as $n=p+q$, where $p$ is a prime and $q$ is a product of at most two primes.

I would like a representation $n=p_1+p_2p_3$ in which all three constituent primes are close to each other, say in the range $[n^{1/3},n^{2/3}]$ or some other interval around $n^{1/2}$.  Am I out of luck?  If so, can one say anything about the density of integers with such a representation as a function of the allowed interval width?

I am a total novice here, but assuming Chen's theorem admits a proof by sieve methods then perhaps the 'bad' representations for my purpose can be estimated and subtracted from the total.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Also, can one demand anything extra about the ordering of the primes involved, such as $p_1<p_2<p_3$?

Comment: These sieve methods automatically yield representations with primes that are not that small, say $>n^\delta$ for some fixed $\delta>0$. Note, however, that we can't guarantee that there are any representations of the form $p_1+p_2p_3$: for all we know, all the representations are actually of the form $p_1+p_2$.

Comment: It may be of some help to quickly sketch the proof of Chen's theorem: Consider the values $N-p$ for $2<p<N$, say $n=N-p$. Chen shows that there are many such values such that $w(n)>0$, where $$w(n)=1-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\substack{p\mid n\\ z<p<y}}1-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\substack{p_1p_2p_3=n\\ z<p_1<y<p_2<p_3}}1.$$ It turns out that one has to take $z=N^{1/8}$, and $y=N^{1/3}$. So, in the worst case scenario, $w(n)>0$ solely due to the $n=p_1p_2$ where  $z<p_1<y<p_2$. However, as Greg pointed out, this isn't the only scenario in which $w(n)>0$.

Comment: Considering the $n=p_1p_2$ above, it is also possible that $y<p_1<p_2$. However, $n$ could not have more than 2 prime factors bigger than $y$ since then $N=y^3<p_1p_2p_3\le n<N$, an absurdity.